# How to apply Aero-Snap to an borderless Stage

Tags: java, windows, javafx, aero-snap

I am trying to apply Aero-Snap to an borderless Stage, but the native Windows functions are disabled.

I was searching for an answer to that question but I didn't found one.

Summarized I just want to add Aero-Snap to a Stage with that setting:
`.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);`

Comment: As it is right now, you unfortunately have to implement this behavior yourself. So you need to listen to key combinations and adjust the position and size of your stage accordingly.

Comment: thats sad, but thanks for your answer!

Comment: Indeed. This was one of the first things I discovered when I started looking into JavaFX. The aero-snap functionality should hopefully not be that difficult to implement though. I created my own decorated window pane as my first "trying to learn Javafx" -project and unfortunately I had some issues with the stage "flickering" when being resized. Not sure if it has been fixed by now though, but it was a known bug back then (jdk 8).